# Use Quartz to trigger Javascript popup

Tags: grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler

Friends,

I'm working on a Grails application. This app has a reminder function and I want Grails to periodically check if there are open reminders. This is done using the Quartz-plugin. If an open reminder is found, I want to show a popup (using Javascript alert). How does this work?

This is what I have now:

**Job**

```
class checkRemindersJob {

    HomeController myHome = new HomeController()

    static triggers = { cron name: 'myTrigger', cronExpression: "0 * * ? * *" }

    def execute() {
        myHome.checkReminder()
    }
}
```

**Controller Home**

```
def checkReminder(){

    def myRem = Reminders.findAllBy...
    if( myRem.size > 0 ) triggerReminders( myRem )
}

def triggerReminders( ArrayList myRem ){

    for( x in myRem ) {
        if(...) triggerPopup()
    }
}

def triggerPopup(){
    ????
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach won't work, because you can't trigger JavaScript from a Quartz job. Also, your Quartz job is instantiating and calling a controller action, which is not recommended (and unlikely to work).

Instead, try the following

- use the JavaScript `setInterval()` function to repeatedly make an AJAX request to `HomeController.checkReminder`
- this action should return the reminder data in JSON format
- the callback of the AJAX request should read the reminder data and show the popup if there are open reminders

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could attack this challenge using a lightweight REST API and do the timings in JavaScript:

- The Grails app has a Reminder, which is exposed as a REST resource
- JavaScript on the client regularly calls the REST resource and updates a local list
- The JS triggers a UI event if the list changes.

That way you've got clients polling your server, which follows the standard model normal web requests follow.

If you want the Grails server to push messages to the client you need to look at technologies like WebRTC or WebSockets, which keeps bidirectional channels open, but that sounds like overkill for what you're trying to achieve.